# BrowserSync: Refused to execute inline script, Anchor Tags not working

Tags: javascript, security, browser-sync

When I click on the anchor tags it takes me to /null and displays this error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-KpHv3zgivMSB4dPnfYfqMt2lBibsYvM36EdoBBAsfbM='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body><script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.3'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>

<pre>Cannot GET /block-examples/null</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding meta tag for CSP, but what didn't work.